# Not able to change view colour in UICollection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uibackgroundcolor

I am trying to change colour of the view inside the uicollectionviewcell. But I am not able to change the colour. When I try to connect to the UIViewController to our view controller it say  " cannot connect the repetitive content as an outlet.".

When I change the background of the cell it comes like this [image]

As to make it round I am using view and the giving it layer radius properties.

What I am trying to achieve is:
[image]

The values are coming from the model class that I have created and assigned it to UIcolectionviewcell. Model contains only one text field that shows the tags.

When user select any tags the background and text colour  will change.I am not to achieve this. It might be easy to do but somehow I am not able to achieve this.

Comment: And how is create the white background with layer radius? You are trying to connect a View from a Prototype Cell to your UIViewController? Don't. Just use a Custom UICollectionViewCell with its own UIView property that you can color as you wish.

Comment: But how to do that when user taps on the cell. As I am not able to change the colour of view inside the cell.

Comment: Put some code along with your question to understand what you have tried and what you are doing wrong here.

Comment: For collectionViewCell you must create a class for your cell and connect your view in that class and customize your views. I recommend you to read UICollectionView tutorials.

Comment: Custom class helped me in achieving the round with the change in background colour.

with custom class and this code in it.

 
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) { 
        super.draw(rect)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    }



But not able to change the text color. When he click on the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the background color of your rounded element and not of the entire cell
You can create custom UICollectionViewCell and use it to access different items inside of it, like the textfield with your tag

Answer (score 1):

I've added the sample code to achieve your requirements, Please refer and try implementing based on the following code:

```
//Your model class
class TagModel{

    var tag:String!
    var selected:Bool!

    init(tag:String, selected:Bool) {

        self.tag = tag
        self.selected = selected
    }
}

//your cell with Xib
class TagCell:UICollectionViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var tagLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    func setTag(_ tagModel:TagModel){

        tagLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
        tagLabel.layer.cornerRadius = tagLabel.frame.size.height/2

        tagLabel.text = tagModel.tag

        if tagModel.selected{

            tagLabel.textColor = .white
            tagLabel.backgroundColor = .blue
        }else{

            tagLabel.textColor = .gray
            tagLabel.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        }
    }
}

//Your ViewController which has `UICollectionView`
class TagViewController:UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{

    var tagModels:[TagModel]!

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        tagModels[indexPath.item].selected = !tagModels[indexPath.item].selected

        collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
    }
}
```

**Note: Please take this code as sample and make modifications based on your implementations.**